# Getting attribute text error after running tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, text, internationalization

I'm Korean, and I used Korean language text in attribute table.

I ran `Add raster values to points`. (input shapefile and raster(aspect))

The tool works well, but result file's attribute table has an error. Every Korean text character is changed to a question mark (`?`).

[image]

How can I maintain Korean text in an attribute table after running the tool `add raster values to points`?

Comment: Check the `Data source encoding` (Layer Properties > Source). It may be set to UTF-8. Change the encoding to your original one.